# image grid with vertical floating and dynamic number of columns, is this possible?

Tags: php, image, grid

I am working on an image grid in which the images have a fixed height and width and spread out across the width of the screen, justified to the left en right edge.

This is the current example: http://www.samweerdmeester.nl/main/main.php

Right now the images are retrieved form the database from new to old, and are arranged horizontally with the standard CSS float:left property. The thing is:

--> I want the images arranged vertically! <---  So image 21 should occupy the upper left corner like it does now, but image 20, should be placed underneath that one, and 19 underneath that one, untill that first column reaches it maximum number of images (based on total amount of images, and space for columns) and then the next image should start at the top of column two and so on.

I think I would manage if I had a fixed number of columns, but with the number of columns being dynamic dependent of current browser width and screen resolution, I would not know where to strart, or even if it's possible. Any suggestion, be it PHP or jquery or some badly supported CSS is welcome!

many thanks Sam

Comment: is this a strange topic?? no one a suggestion?

Comment: 'googled', found these that may be useful: [Youtube: CSS - HTML Elements in Columns, Vertically Ordered](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WzyNVoZ6hog). Also, [Fluid-multi-column-vertically-ordered-list-using-CSS](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38964/Fluid-multi-column-vertically-ordered-list-using-C).